# How to disable html form from navigating on submit?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have this form

```
<form onsubmit="submitData();">
    <input type="text" pattern="^[A-z]+$" required>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Upon clicking the submit button, I don't want the form to post any data in the address bar or navigate anywhere, I just want it to run the submitData function and thats it. The reason I want to use the form is because of its validating functionality (it wont let you submit if the input text is missing or doesn't match the pattern).

If I switch the value of onsubmit on the form to "return false;" then it won't navigate but "submitData(); return false;" doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: `return false`  in function

Comment: @uzaif - `return false` will not run anything after it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning of your code, with the event being passed to your `function submitData(e) {`, like this:

```
function submitData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

Just add `event.preventDefault` that is automatically pass by the form to the function:

```
function submitData(event){
   event.preventDefault();    
   //your code will be here
}
```

read more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault()`.

Learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

```
document.getElementById("addYourTagHERE").addEventListener("onsubmit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
    });
```

or this in your function:

```
function submitData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: event type (the first addEventListener parameter) is `submit` and not `onsubmit`

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to **cancel the default action** of the submit `event` handler, so:

```
function submitData() {
    // whatever logic you have...
    return false;
}
```

I believe this works too:

```
function submitData( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // whatever logic you have...
}
```